# Extracting road distance without Google Maps API

Tags: maps, distance

Is there a global alternative to Google Maps API related primarily to the extraction of road distances?

Say, I have latitude and longitude information for a great number of locations, in which I would like to build a matrix of distances. Google sets a limit to our queues (2500 daily extractions), which is significantly lower than what I need. Instead of paying google or doing approximations with geodesic distances, what would be my alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Distancematrix.ai](https://distancematrix.ai/product?utm_source=SFlow&utm_medium=Answer&utm_campaign=Dev_3). This is an alternative to Google Maps Distance Matrix API, but it has even more advantages.
Main features:

- Unlimited matrix size
- Accounts for traffic conditions, traffic jams, and restrictions
- Distances are calculated to account for driving, walking, or bicycling
- Departure and arrival time option is used to build a forecast
- Easy migration, you have just to switch endpoint

Disclaimer: I work at the company that creates the API.